# Unable to login to Google Cloud

Tags: python, windows-7, cygwin, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am using Cygwin terminal on Windows 7 to login to 'Google Cloud', but am coming across the following error:

$ *gcloud auth login*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cygdrive/c/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 64, in <module>
    resource_registration.RegisterReleasedAPIs()
  File "/cygdrive/c/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/resource_registration.py", line 16, in RegisterReleasedAPIs
    from googlecloudapis.compute import v1 as compute_v1
  File "/cygdrive/c/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudapis/compute/v1/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    __path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extend_path'**
```

I think I am using the latest version (downloaded it two days back) and I was not getting this error yesterday. I didn't change anything on my system. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,